# Logger is locking the log file. Unable to create new log file

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, logging

I am using TimedRotatingFileHandler logger in my flask app. When a HTTP request is sent to app first time, the code executes and creates a log file APIlog.log successfully. When second HTTP request is sent, same piece of code is executed and give me exception about log file being used by another process.

Below is thrown exception:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 72, in emit
    self.doRollover()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 393, in doRollover
    self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 113, in rotate
    os.rename(source, dest)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\ProjectFiles\\ExceptionLogFiles\\APIlog' -> 'C:\\ProjectFiles\\ExceptionLogFiles\\APIlog.2020_02_06.log'
Call stack:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\threading.py", line 891, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\threading.py", line 923, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\threading.py", line 871, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\socketserver.py", line 628, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\socketserver.py", line 684, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 327, in handle
    rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\http\server.py", line 415, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 362, in handle_one_request
    return self.run_wsgi()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 304, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 294, in execute
    for data in application_iter:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\__init__.py", line 330, in debug_application
    app_iter = self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\plugin\ferc\api\api.py", line 30, in validate
    app.logger.debug("New : CID: {}, Period:{}, Year:{}, FileName:{}".format(cid,period,year,filename))
Message: 'New : CID: C00123, Period:Q4, Year:2016, FileName:TEST.doc'
Arguments: ()
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2020 16:26:34] "POST /validate HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 269, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1967, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2097, in make_response
    "The view function did not return a valid response. The"
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

Following is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from json import dumps
from flask_jsonpify import jsonify
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_output
from datetime import datetime
import os
import configparser
import adodbapi
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
from collections import OrderedDict
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@app.route('/validate', methods=['POST'])
def validate():
    try:

        date =  datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H-%M-%S')
        cid = request.form.get("cid")
        period = request.form.get("period")
        year = request.form.get("year")
        form = request.form.get("form")
        filename = request.files.get("file").filename        
        app.logger.debug("New : CID: {}, Period:{}, Year:{}, FileName:{}".format(cid,period,year,filename))


    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.exception("validate function: Something went wrong. ", exc_info=True)
        return '"INVALID FILE"'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    logFilePath = "C:/ProjectFiles/ExceptionLogFiles/"
    logger = logging.getLogger('APIlogger')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-5s %(message)s', datefmt='%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S')
    #fh = TimedRotatingFileHandler(logFilePath + 'APIlog',when='midnight')
    fh = TimedRotatingFileHandler(logFilePath + 'APIlog',when = 's', interval = 30, backupCount = 20)
    fh.suffix = "%Y_%m_%d.log"
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)    
    app.logger.addHandler(fh)
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port='80')
```

Please can anyone help me resolving this locking issue.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm having the same issue.